# hover over only 1 element with same class jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, hover, css-selectors

I have this code in jquery:

```
$(".pun").hover(function() {
 $(".guns").show(0);        
});
```

My html

```
<div class="pun">
<div class="guns">gun 1</div>
</div>
<div class="pun">
<div class="guns">gun 2</div>
</div>
<div class="pun">
<div class="guns">gun 3</div>
</div>
```

My css

```
.pun {
display:visible
}

.guns {
display:none
}
```

I want to do hover action display only the item that is being **hovering**. Now if you doing hover show every divs guns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show only the `guns` div that's inside of the `pun` div you're hovering, use the `find` function

```
$(".pun").hover(function() {
   $(this).find(".guns").show(0);        
});
```

Or provide a context for your selector

```
$(".pun").hover(function() {
   $(".guns", this).show(0);        
});
```

Also, the default for `show` performs no animation, so you can replace `.show(0);` with just `show();`

Answer (score 3):

This is much more easily accomplished using CSS only:

```
div.pun div.guns {
    display: none;
}

div.pun:hover div.guns {
    display: block;
}
```

Btw, `visible` isn't a valid value for the `display` property. And also, you're missing the second argument to `hover()` (if you stick with jQuery). You should probably `hide()` the `.guns` in the second function or if you only want to show them (and never hide them) you can just use `mouseover()` instead of `hover()`.

Comment: while I agree that this is a better way to accomplish the same thing; that was not the question asked. The question was about doing it with jquery.

Comment: If by older you mean IE6 and below. @Chad - true. But if someone asked how to create a two column layout using tables I wouldn't tell that person how - I would describe how to do it properly.

Comment: _However_, if not hiding the guns onmouseout() (or second function in hover()) was intentional the CSS solution won't work. If that's the case your answer is obviously better. I'll give it a +1 for that.

Comment: Looks like even IE7 doesn't like :hover http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762  But your answer was a breath of fresh air, so +1  ---

Comment: Display visible its for understand the state from .pun. I have not display visible in my css :D.. Thanks

Comment: @AdamRackis - Well, if you're coding in quirks mode you really shouldn't be coding.

Comment: @powerbuoy - ahhh - I didn't read the article closely enough -- I'm no expert on crappy IE support.  Glad to hear IE7 supports this under normal circumstances

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$(".guns").show(0);
```

To

```
$(".guns", this).show(0);
```

That will select only the `'.guns'` within the context of the hovered element. ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsLPk/))

Answer (score 1):

In hover there are two `events` bounded, `mouseover` and `mouseout`. you might want to hide it on `mouseout`

```
$(".pun").hover(function() {
   $(this).children(".guns").show(100);        
},function(){
   $(this).children(".guns").hide(100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify them by id, or something like this should work (untested):

```
$(".pun").hover(function() {
    $(this).children(".guns:first").show(0);        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a subselect

```
$(".pun").hover(function() {
    $(this).children(".guns").show(0);        
});
```